# Installing operating system from server PC to all the client PC

Tags: networking, batch-file, operating-system

I am working on the project in which I have decided to install operating system from server PC to all the client PC.
I have one windows iso file on the server PC which is shared on the network.

1. This iso file will be first transfered or copied to all the client pc.
2. Once the iso file is copied to a specific folder in the client machine I have a batch file which is scheduled to run the setup.exe of the windows.
3. The setup is started but once the setup is started the windows will be restart.

my problem is once the windows is started how do I control that setup window the setup asks for which language to choose, partition, and other operations....

How should I automate this process without choosing any of the message or how should I pass commands from server to the client so that the I can continue the windows installation.

Is there any way to edit windows file so that it will be take the default language and other options.

Thank-you

Comment: for windows 10 / Server 2016 look here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-unattended-media-do-automated-installation-windows-10

Comment: Will it work if I am not using USB. Just simply copying the autounattend.xml in the folder of setup and double click on the setup and start the setup.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you should use the [Windows Setup Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-command-line-options).

In particular, the `/unattend` switch allows you to specify an [answer file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/windows-system-image-manager-technical-reference) to provide the information the Windows Setup GUI would otherwise need to ask for.